# Can't unmute with alsamixer

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in combination with Awesome window manager. Most of the stuff ubuntu provides I don't use.

I adjust my audio volume through scripts with `amixer` or manually with `alsamixer`. However after a reboot, my audio is muted and the only way to unmute it is through the `gnome-control-center sound` GUI.

I prefer terminal so I would like to know how I can unmute my audio without having to open up a GUI. Also, should I maybe remove pulseaudio, since I always use alsamixer anyways?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65764/how-do-i-toggle-sound-with-amixer), as for pulseaudio, remove if you don't use it.

Comment: After muting with Alsa mixer and keeping it like that for just over an hour I had my sound ununmuteable via Alsa mixer. A suspend-wake didn't help. @Takkat's answer did. (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case we want to keep pulseaudio we may also unmute a sink from the command line.

By using the [Pulseaudio Command Line Interface](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/CLI) we will get the index of available sinks

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

We then can unmute the sink with

```
pacmd set-sink-mute <index> 0
```

Comment: For a more compact list you might want to use: `pacmd list-sinks|grep "index:\|name:\|muted:"`

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that every time your reboot you need to unmute then you can avoid the problem completely by unmuting manually once then run

```
sudo alsactl store
```

Next time you reboot, your settings will be automatically restored.